# Designing an ad for The Looking Glass

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

There are one or two ads I think we could really use:

1. An ad for [The Looking Glass chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36555/the-looking-glass)
2. An ad directly to the Critique Guidelines

(it may not be a bad idea to put an ad to the Font Guidelines as well)

I think especially for [The Looking Glass](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36555/the-looking-glass) there's a lot of ideas and stuff that comes to mind, perhaps even someone that needs a piece for their portfolio would like to do it.

What ideas and concepts can you all come up with? I propose people put up their ideas and be open to let others build and refine on it and once we get something with a decent number of upvotes we add it to our [Community Promotions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3076/community-promotion-ads-2017).

Comment: @Ryan: maybe you should open a second Q for point nr 2 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Posted on [Community Promotion Ads](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/63979) (*See full stats [here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3076)*)

---

What about something like this, where we utilize our "true" colors to the fullest.

[image]

Comment: "STOP THE LOOKING GLASS"

Comment: @ZachSaucier It was all a *hidden* message... I'm really the **evil devil** trying to destroy The Looking Glass!

Comment: ooh I like this a lot. other than thinking it could use some more manual kerning on a few characters I'd be good with this one.

Comment: @Ryan It's because the font I used didn't have a bold option, and I wanted those words to **stick** out... so I did `Offset Path` for those few words, hence the bad kerning.  I agree with you and that can all be fixed relatively easily...

Comment: why not use a simpler message? "looking for advice? head over to the looking glass". Then "advice" and "the looking glass" could use the same accent color

Comment: @Luciano I like your idea of more simple, but I wanted to have those colors specifically (our *site colors*).

Comment: I'd opt to remove "stop looking" and change "head over to" to "come visit" or "stop by" because they're more *welcoming* rather than *sending*

Comment: Looks well @WELZ :) Have you viewed it at display size though? I'm wondering if the type weight will be lost when it's displayed in side panel dimensions?

Comment: @johnp I think [this looks good](http://i.stack.imgur.com/S7Yjl.jpg), but I'd love to get additional feedback from everyone.

Comment: Welz I think you did a great job. Could you post it over in the https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3076/community-promotion-ads-2017 so we can get it running

Answer (score 3):

[image]

PNG version can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL7s7.png).

Very rudimentary first attempt. I think there's people here who can make this a lot better, so have at it. The slogan I think it kinda speaks for itself.

- Font is Open Sans Bold in #ea4858
- Image was taken from [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/search/grandma?photo=y0I85D5QKvs)

EDIT: added a higher quality version.

Comment: The phrasing seems a little off to me. Come seems more inviting to where we are. And "fellas" has a connotation of men. So I'd changing it to "If you only want praise for your work, go talk to Grandma. For honest critique and feedback, come talk to the people in The Looking Glass". Maybe also put a small GD logo in the bottom right so they know it's affiliated with the site itself

Comment: Yeah, the phrasing was from the point of view of the grandma; like the grandma is saying this to her grandchild. I agree with the 'fellas'. Adding the logo is a good idea.

Comment: The plain black and white photo reminds me of ASPCA commercials

Comment: I don't know what that is

Comment: https://youtu.be/IO9d2PpP7tQ

Comment: "Every hour an innocent designer makes a crappy logo." - "They don't know any better." - "All they need is a little helping hand." - GDSE helps

Comment: @PieBie  Best ad text ever.

Comment: Lol. For more of those shenanigans see... The Looking Glass :)

Comment: Agree with @ZachSaucier, switch the words "go" and "come" and you're all set.

Comment: @PieBie, you should make that into an ad.  :)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This one is a bit more in line with our *corporate style*. Not as eye catching as grandma, but maybe a tad more to the point?

[image]

Comment: "Free ambiance" lol